# Update the selected random row PHP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to update the selected random row in database here is my php code

```
$offset_result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * COUNT(*)) AS `offset` FROM `tbl_combi` WHERE `clear` = 0 ");
$offset_row = mysqli_fetch_object( $offset_result );
$offset = $offset_row->offset;
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `tbl_combi` LIMIT $offset, 1");    
$result_fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

echo $result_fetch[1];
```

Comment: so whats the issue?

Comment: sorry I just know what to do now hehe

Comment: what values do you want to update?

Comment: maybe try an update query then?

Comment: I already made what I want to do, Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: Do you have contiguous id fields, or at least a fairly even spread? Does the record updated have to be VERY random, or is close to random sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never perform any update. Here is something you could try (it might need some tuning to fit your need) :

```
$offset_result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * COUNT(*)) AS `offset` FROM `tbl_combi` WHERE `clear` = 0 ");
$offset_row = mysqli_fetch_object( $offset_result );
$offset = $offset_row->offset;

$updateSql = 'UPDATE tbl_combi SET my_field="my_value" WHERE offset=' . $offset;
mysqli_query($conn, $updateSql);

$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `tbl_combi` LIMIT $offset, 1");    
$result_fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

echo $result_fetch[1];
```

Comment: hello @vincenth thank your for your help but I tried another way and it's already updating my only problem now is it still includes the row with clear = 0. `$offset_result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * COUNT(*)) AS offset FROM tbl_combi WHERE clear = 0 ");`

Comment: I tried this code `do{
   $offset_result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * COUNT(*)) AS offset FROM tbl_combi WHERE clear = 0 ");
   $offset_row = mysqli_fetch_object( $offset_result );
   $offset = $offset_row->offset;
   $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM tbl_combi LIMIT $offset, 1"); 
   $result_fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($result); 
  }while($result_fetch[3] == 1);` it's working but it thanks time